# Validation for textbox by using checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

This is my code:

```
<input type="password" id="centraPassword" placeholder="Enter Centra Password" class="form-control" ng-model="centraPassword" />

<label>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="centrapasswordcheck" >
   I have a Centra Travels password
</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="continueEmailButton" id="btnContinue" ng-click="ContinueDetails()">Continue</button>
```

This is my angularjs Code:

```
$scope.ContinueDetails = function () {
if ($scope.centrapasswordcheck == true)
         {
if ($scope.centraPassword == '' || $scope.centraPassword == null) {
alert("please enter your password")
    return;
             }
         }
 }
```

In the above code when I click the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button, first check the checkbox checked or not after it will check enter the password or not.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: When i click a check box ng-model does't workout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
module.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.centrapasswordcheck = true;
  
  $scope.ContinueDetails = function () {
    if ($scope.centrapasswordcheck == true) {
      if ($scope.centraPassword == '' || $scope.centraPassword == null) {
        alert("please enter your password 1");
      }
      else {
        alert("Password Validated");
      }
    } else {
      alert('Please Check Checkbox');
    }
    alert('Coming out of the fuction');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="password" id="centraPassword" placeholder="Enter Centra Password" class="form-control" ng-model="centraPassword" />

<label>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="centrapasswordcheck" >
   I have a Centra Travels password
</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="!centrapasswordcheck" id="btnContinue" ng-click="ContinueDetails()">Continue</button>
  </body>
```

Check Once Is it what you want or something else

Remove alerts ands code what you want